# Insert record in relation table in sugarCrm?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am new in sugar crm, trying to insert records in related tables but not getting the way to do the same.

I have two modules **quotes and product** a product can have one/multiple quotes for it. so created a relation one-to-many and a table called **product_quotes** get generated which consist the ids of both the parent table.

I am able to insert the data in the main tables but not getting the way to save there ids on the  product_quotes.

I am doing all the things on a scheduler task.